# How to make a "Video Wall"

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro

I'm currently trying to make a "video wall". It should look [something like this](https://twitter.com/singhcredible/status/1651561505798901761).

I have Final Cut Pro but the process was more tedious than I'd originally anticipated.

Is there a better, preferably free (no plugins) way to easily to this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Motion and make a template with Drop Zones and then fill the zones with videos in FCP.